# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') at HTMLInputElement.geocodio

Tags: javascript

I am having issues trying to run an API using Geocodio. This is set up through WordPress and I would really appreciate any help I can get!

Everything works up until the actual API itself has to run. The [Geocodio](https://www.geocod.io/docs/#client-side-access) documentation states that it runs "using a jQuery AJAX call". I have tried multiple script sources that claim to fix the problem, but I get the error that "superfish() is not a function" or that "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')".

```
<head>
    <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="superfish.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="myTxt" style="width: 400px;" placeholder="Type Your Address Here!"></input>
    <input type="submit" id="myBtn" value="Search Now!"></input>
    <script>
        var submit = document.getElementById("myBtn")
        var myInput = document.getElementById("myTxt")
        submit.addEventListener("click", geocodio)
        
        function geocodio() {
            if(myInput.value.length == 0) {
                alert("Please input a valid address")
            }
            else {
                $.get('https://api.geocod.io/v1.7/geocode?q='+ encodeURIComponent(myInput) 
                +'&api_key=' + encodeURIComponent('YOUR_API_KEY'), function (response) {
                console.log(response.results)});
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `encodeURIComponent(myInput)` - `myInput` is the `<input>` element itself. You probably wanted to write `encodeURIComponent(myInput.value)`. Just as you check `myInput.value.length` a bit earlier.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! This was something I missed, thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using some strange version of jQuery that forces you to refer to it as `jQuery` and not `$`. Odd, I thought all versions of jQuery also set up the `$` global.

Try replacing `$` with `jQuery` inside `geocodio()`:

```js
function geocodio() {
    if (myInput.value.length == 0) {
        alert("Please input a valid address")
    }
    else {
        jQuery.get('https://api.geocod.io/v1.7/geocode?q=' + encodeURIComponent(myInput.value)
        + '&api_key=' + encodeURIComponent('YOUR_API_KEY'), function (response) {
            console.log(response.results);
        });
    }
}
```

(also fixed: encode `myInput.value` instead of encoding whole input)

If that doesn't work, perhaps `jQuery.js` failed to load. Check the console messages and/or network trace tab in the developer tools.

If that doesn't work, try stepping thru the code using the JavaScript debugger built in to your browser ([short tutorial video](https://youtu.be/H0XScE08hy8)).

Comment: That was the solution! Additionally encoding myInput.value was something I missed on my end too, but thank you for catching that! 

I appreciate the prompt response and am so happy this made it work like a charm!! I hope you have a wonderful rest of your day or night! :)